Custom Python Module folders not being detected
This feels like it shouldn't be a massive issue but here I am. I am currently attempting to get this code for a Discord bot running for my own purposes. (https://github.com/pxlsspace/Clueless) File Tree: My Visual Studio Code window Here is a picture of my file tree and the imports of my speed.py file.
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

import disnake
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from disnake.ext import commands

from utils.arguments_parser import parse_speed_args
from utils.discord_utils import format_number, image_to_file
from utils.image.image_utils import hex_str_to_int, v_concatenate
from utils.plot_utils import add_glow, fig2img, get_theme, hex_to_rgba_string
from utils.pxls.cooldown import get_best_possible
from utils.setup import db_stats, db_users
from utils.setup import stats as stats_manager
from utils.table_to_image import table_to_image
from utils.time_converter import (
    format_datetime,
    format_timezone,
    get_datetimes_from_input,
    round_minutes_down,
    td_format,
)
from utils.timezoneslib import get_timezone
from utils.utils import in_executor, shorten_list

When I debug using the VSC debugger, I get the error:
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'utils'
  File "C:\Users\malak\Desktop\Aware\src\cogs\pxls\speed.py", line 7, in <module>
    from utils.arguments_parser import parse_speed_args
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

and I can't figure out why packages I've installed using pip are found just fine, but the ones in subdirectories of the project are not. speed.py is just an example as well; it does the same thing for any cog that requires an import from another subdirectory.
